# highlighting text in html textarea using java

Tags: html, jsf

I develop a web based system using jsf and java.

If there is a similarities between keyword entered by user and keyword stored in mysql database then the keyword will be highlight.

It is possible to highlighting some keyword entered by user in jsf inputtextarea using java?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, what JSF does is generate HTML tags (a `<textarea>` in this case), so what JSF can do is limited by the capabilities of the underlying HTML control used. While you can control the style of an entire textarea, you cannot control parts of its content separately.

You can however achieve this using javascript (hide the textarea, create a div that looks like a textarea and highlight what you want in it). There are plugins that already do this, for example take a look at this one: http://www.strangeplanet.fr/work/jquery-highlighttextarea/ (requires jQuery, a javascript framework).